# Importing Textures from other .blend files

Tags: cycles-render-engine, interface, workflow, hdri

I recently downloaded a Model from *blendswap*, and I really like the **Environmental Texture(HDRI)** that they've used in their scene, but I don't seem to find it anywhere on my computer. Where can I find their HDRI, How can I use this HDRI in one of my own Blend files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can append all sort of things from one blend file to another. File>append>go to the file with what you want> enter it and you get a list (action, brush, camera..., texture), enter texture and you might find there. Other way, is to open the blend file with the HDRI, go to UV image editor, select the HDRI to view it, press F3 to export it, by doing that, you might edit it in external software, like Gimp, or similar.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you can actually see the HDRI in question when you render from the Blend file, it is likely that the HDRI image is packed inside the file. You won't see it locally on your disk unless you unpack it.

If you go to the UV/Image Editor, you can see a list of all images in use by clicking on the button on the bottom panel to the right of the `UVs` menu (or `Image` menu if you don't have an object selected).

With the HDRI image selected, you can then save it out (from the `Image` menu).

If the HDRI is not in that list, and you cannot see it when you render from the Blend file, the person who made it probably didn't include it in the distribution (perhaps because they didn't have the necessary rights).